# Using decorators with class

Tags: python, python-decorators

I am trying to add a decorator to required class methods and I have come up with the following code for it. I need this to work with all the similar classes.

```
import allure

def class_method_dec(cls):
    """
    Decorator function to decorate required class methods.
    """
    if cls.method1:
        cls.method1= allure.step(cls.method1)

    if cls.method2:
        cls.method2= allure.step(cls.method2)

    if cls.method3:
        cls.method3= allure.step(cls.method3)

    return cls


@class_method_dec
class TestClass:

    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def method1(self):
        """
        method docstring
        """
        pass

    def method2(self):
        """
        method docstring
        """
        pass

    def method3(self):
        """
        method docstring
        """
        pass
```

Is this the right way to do it? I am looking for the best way to do this.

Also, I understand that we can use functools.wraps to preserve the docstring when decorating functions. Is there a need of something like it when we are decorating classes?

Comment: If you need the docstrings intact, then you need to do something like `functools.wrap(cls.method)(allure.step(cls.method1))`, i guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Satwik Kansal’s brilliant [Metaprogramming in Python](https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/ba-metaprogramming-python/) IBM tutorial , I discovered this gem:

Satwik first defined a decorator:

```py
from functools import wraps
import random
import time

def wait_random(min_wait=1, max_wait=30):
    def inner_function(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(args, **kwargs):
            time.sleep(random.randint(min_wait, max_wait))
            return func(args, **kwargs)

        return wrapper

    return inner_function
```

And then he created a class wrapper that will apply this decorator to a class:

```py
def classwrapper(cls):
    for name, val in vars(cls).items():
        #callable return True if the argument is callable
        #i.e. implements the __call
        if callable(val):
            #instead of val, wrap it with our decorator.
            setattr(cls, name, wait_random()(val))
    return cls
```

Application:

```py
# decorate a function

@wait_random(10, 15)
def function_to_scrape():
    #some scraping stuff

# decorate a class

@classwrapper
class Scraper:
    # some scraping stuff
```

To make use of it in your case, substitute  `wait_random` decorator with your own. Turn your function to a decorator.
E.g

```py
from functools import wraps
import allure

def apply_allure():
    def inner_function(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(args, **kwargs):
            func = allure.step(func)
            return func(args, **kwargs)

        return wrapper

    return inner_function
```

In the `classwrapper` replace `wait_random` with `apply_allure`:

Do read the tutorial for more information and explanations

Comment: There is one small change needed in the inner_function. In wrapper, before returning the func(args, **kwargs), it should be func = allure.step(func). 
The shared article is a very good resource.

Comment: That `apply_allure` is far more complex than it needs to be - the whole function could be eliminated, and the call site simplified to use `allure.step(val)` instead of `apply_allure()(val)`. Also, the `classwrapper` wraps methods like `__init__` that were not wrapped in the original code and probably shouldn't be wrapped.

Comment: Oh! Thanks. I have not worked with allure. I was only answering how to wrap a class.